# How can I use vscode proxy for the request on my code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, proxy

I was set the proxy setting in vscode and all of the extentions can use it normally.
But I found the http request in my code without use the proxy, like in the vite server.
Now I used the `http-proxy-agent` to use proxy with my local like this:

```js
import { HttpProxyAgent } from 'http-proxy-agent';

const agent = new HttpProxyAgent('socks5://127.0.0.1:7890');

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
...
server: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8088,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: require('./server/env').api.host,
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
        agent,
      },
   }
}
}));
```

It's working, but it have to change my code for just only to use proxy.

I want to know why the VSCode proxy setting not working with request in my code? Has any wonder method to reolve my prolem?

Hear is my VSCode setting:

```
  "http.proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:7890",
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
```

When I don't use agent with vite, It has a Error:

```bash
[vite] http proxy error:                                                                                          20:02:54
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.25.170.17:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) (x6)
```